# How to insert a datetime at european format in BDD

Tags: php, mysql, date, format

I insert a date in PHP created like that :

```
$myDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

It works perfectly. If I change the format like that :

```
$myDate = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

The value inserted is `0000-00-00...`
It exsists a way to insert a date in French format ?

Comment: Not sure how to do this in PHP. However, here is a hint, as implemented in AMP: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-date-display/. IMO you're going to need a library that takes data in an ISO date format (the default that you show in your first example) and formats the data (date) according to your desired format.

Comment: You are confusing data storage and retrieval with data display. Always store dates using a date data type, and then display them in the format of your locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MYSQL only allows `yyyy-mm-dd` format for storage so it is impossible to store dates in the French format. 
You can change the field type to be a `char` or any other string type if you want to store the dates in any format of your choice but you won't be able to perform MYSQL date functions, during queries, on the field.
It is better to follow the standard format and have a script convert the date to whatever format you want when you want to display the date to users.